# Importance of undergrad GPA, when you have a masters, applying for phd?

Tags: phd, application, international-students

Background: I'm a fourth year student studying a commerce and science degree at one of the top univerisities in Australia, namely, Monash University. My majors are in finance and mathematics.
Unfortunately I didn't do well in the first two years of my degree and my GPA is, in short, very average.
However, I plan to do an honours in finance (if I can get in) or masters in econometrics/statistics/financial mathematics (for which I satisfy the pre requisites). The institution I attend is very reputable in econemtrics.
I really have only been thinking about doing a phd for a few days now, and want to apply to NYU's finance or statistics program, 3 or 4 years down the road. 
With a 2.5/4 GPA in my undergraduate, are my chances severely diminished even if my postgraduate scores are stellar, and have a competitive GMAT score?
If it makes a difference, my undergraduate GPA in my commerce(finance) degree alone is something like 3.2(granted not great, but better than a 2.5!) it's the science component which drags me down.
I don't know too much about American univerisities but have accepted that there isn't a chance in hell for me to get into Ivy's like Harvard, but would am still heavily interested in NYU tier universities for something in finance or econometrics.
Any help or advice is very much appreciated! Thanks!
Apologies for any typos - am on my phone.

Comment: _With a 2.5/4 GPA in my undergraduate_ — Hello, and [welcome to the club](http://3dpancakes.typepad.com/ernie/2005/03/re_phd_with_low.html).

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Mad JAck the only (and major) differentiating factor is that OP had poor scores in both his masters and undergrad, whereas I am confident I can do well in a masters field (seeing that I've done some masters subjects in my undergrad on a masters level and performed well on them)